How to view docker image package sizes using docker scout on sbom or other
How to use docker scout to get sbom details from a docker image

docker scout sbom --format list cgr.dev/chainguard/wolfi-base

output:



Name
Version
Type




apk-tools
2.14.4-r0
apk


busybox
1.36.1-r10
apk


busybox
1.36.1-r10
apk


ca-certificates
20240705-r0
apk


ca-certificates-bundle
20240705-r0
apk


glibc
2.40-r1
apk


glibc
2.40-r1
apk


glibc-locale-posix
2.40-r1
apk


glibc-locale-posix
2.40-r1
apk


ld-linux
2.40-r1
apk


libcrypt1
2.40-r1
apk


libcrypto3
3.3.1-r5
apk


libssl3
3.3.1-r5
apk


libxcrypt
4.4.36-r7
apk


openssl
3.3.1-r5
apk


wolfi-base
1-r6
apk


wolfi-baselayout
20230201-r15
apk


wolfi-keys
1-r8
apk


zlib
1.3.1-r4
apk



How can I see the image size in an extra column to the right?

Is there maybe a bash pipe command I can use to create it myself (extracting the size from an external source)? or is there an additional command I can use in the docker scout to show it?

Also curious why:
docker scout cves cgr.dev/chainguard/wolfi-base




Analyzed Image




Target
cgr.dev/chainguard/wolfi-base:latest


digest
2f7a8e1fcd71


platform
linux/amd64


vulnerabilities
0C     0H     0M     0L


size
7.2 MB


packages
16



shows total size as 7.2MB
BUT

docker image inspect

shows. "Size": 15394739:
(ie 15.4mb)
Using docker image ls it also shows as 15.4mb so I assume thats the final image size, but not sure why docker scout cves shows it differently.

The size shown by docker scout cves is the compressed size stored by the registry (and transferred in docker pull). The 15.4 MB will be the uncompressed size on disk.
Regarding formatting, I think the best solution would be to write a program which reads the json output from docker scout and complements it with size data then writes out a new table.
